# How to Get Statistics Running on an ArcGIS Online Hosted Layer?

Tags: arcgis-online

I have Published a Shapefile as a Hosted Layer on ArcGIS Online.

I now want to run some Queries on it, which will include a Group by query,  which can supposedly be done by using the `outStatistics` & `groupByFieldsForStatistics` parameters.

The Help for the `outStatistics` says that

> outStatistics is supported on only those layers/tables that indicate
>   supportsStatistics is true.

How Do I enable this `supportsStatistics` on my hosted feature service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Documentation for Layer/Table](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/layer-table.htm) States:

> `supportsStatistics` would return false in the following scenarios:
>
> - The layer / table resides in a workspace other than an enterprise or    file geodatabase.
> - The layer / table has more than one join defined on    it.
> - The layer / table is joined with another layer / table from a    different workspace.
> - The layer / table has an "outer" join and where    the workspace is a pre-10.1 Geodatabase and application server    connection is used.

Since the Source of this hosted layer is a shapefile, it does not support queryies with Statitistics.

The Solution is to Create a File Geodatabase with this data, and create a Hosted service from it. Only then will you have `supportsStatistics` enabled.